# How to handle JSON Array of String in node js

Tags: node.js, arrays, json

I have a Json in that hobby key value is in string how to handle that and get my expected output.
The file which contains is the actual data. Here I cant able to pas the key value
Here is my code

```
const arr = [];
const file = [
  {
    name: "same",
    hobby: '{ "name": "music", "type": "jazz" }'
  },
];
file.forEach((item) => {
  Object.keys(JSON.parse(item.hobby)).forEach((key) => {
    const base = { ...item, hobby_name: "", hobby_type: "" };
    base.hobby_name= key;
    base.hobby_type= base.hobby_type[key];
    arr.push(base);
  });
});
console.log(arr);
```

output:

```
[ 
 {
    name: "sam",
    content: '{ "h_name": "music", "h_type": "jazz" }',
    content1: "h_name"
    constent2: ""

  },
{
    name: "sam",
    content: '{ "h_name": "music", "h_type": "jazz" }',
    content1: "h_type"
    constent2: ""

  },
];
```

Expected output:

```
 [ 
     {
        name: "sam",
        content: '{ "h_name": "music", "h_type": "jazz" }',
        content1: "h_name"
        constent2: "music"
    
      },
    {
        name: "sam",
        content: '{ "h_name": "music", "h_type": "jazz" }',
        content1: "h_type"
        constent2: "jazz"
    
      },
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the values from the parsed `JSON` object:

```js
const arr = [];
const file = [
  {
    name: "same",
    hobby: '{ "name": "music", "type": "jazz" }'
  },
];
file.forEach((item) => {
  let hobby = JSON.parse(item.hobby);
  Object.keys(hobby).forEach((key) => {
    const base = { "name":item.name, "content":item.hobby };
    base.content1 = `h_${key}`;
    base.content2 = hobby[key];
    arr.push(base);
  });
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

i've just added some changes to your code:

```
const arr = [];
const file = [
  {
    name: "same",
    hobby: '{ "name": "music", "type": "jazz" }'
  },
];
file.forEach((item) => {
  const hobbyObj = JSON.parse(item.hobby);
  
  Object.keys(hobbyObj).forEach((key) => {
    const base = { ...item, hobby_name: "", hobby_type: "" };
    
    base.hobby_name= key;
    base.hobby_type= hobbyObj[key];
    
    arr.push(base);
  });
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const file = [
  {
    name: "same",
    hobby: '{ "name": "music", "type": "jazz" }'
  },
];

let dd = []

file.forEach(
  (it)=>{
    let val = JSON.parse(it.hobby)
    Object.keys(val).map(hby=>
     {
      
      dd.push({
        name:it.name,
        content:it.hobby,
        content1:`h_${hby}`,
        constent2:val[hby]
        })
    }
  )})

console.log(dd)
```